# Create dynamic Metric, which will be based on various dimensions/ filters applied

Tags: mdx

I have a table "Trans" which contains the acccountNumbers and other dimensions like Facility , Status etc.

I need to create a calculated member in SSAS where the logic would be 
Count of Accounts in a group / Total accounts.

Count of Accounts in a group would be based on the Dimension filter I provide.

For e.g. If I provide the facility then I need the Count of accounts (In numerator) group be different facilities.

Likewise If I provide the Status I would need the numerator to be grouped as per the data in Status table.

Table Name 

Trans (AccountNumber, facility,Status) -- This is fact table

Dimension tables 

Facility( Id, Facility_name)

Status (Id, Status)

Not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

`EXISTING` is a useful function, so maybe something like:

```
COUNT(
  EXISTING [AccountNumber].[AccountNumber].MEMBERS
)
```